# Push to GitHub via Magit retrieves error: "error in process sentinel: Symbol’s function definition is void: compat-assoc" but works. How to fix it?

Tags: magit, process, error, symbol-function

I am using Magit in my Emacs. This is [my config file](https://github.com/pdelfino/dotfiles/blob/main/.emacs.d/init.el).

I have been using this package for a long time without issues. Recently, some weird error messages started to appear. After pressing to `push` a branch `elsewhere` being it the branch `origin/my-on-going-pr`, I get an error message:

> error in process sentinel: Symbol’s function definition is void:
> compat-assoc

Weirder than that, the push works. I can see the new commit on GitHub.

If I execute `git push origin on-going-pr-branch` no message is being shown.

Why is this happening? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was just a matter of updating the package to the last version and the problem was solved. I need to do it more often.